# Check integrity constraint violation with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to clean a collection of entities (that is, a table, in the relational jargon), those entities are instances of `Color`, and I want to run a script that uses Doctrine 2 to delete all unreferenced `Color`'s. The problem is that `Color` is referenced by many other entities in the system. So, I could think of two choices:

1. Iterate over all colors and check manually for each one if exists references to a specific `Color` on other entities on my system, and, if there is no reference, delete it.
2. Iterate over all colors and try to delete one, and, if there is a reference to that color, catch the exception trowed by EM caused by Integrity constraint violation, so, I do ignore the failed color and continue with next.

Obviously, the second choice is more simple than the first one, so I've tried that. The problem I had is that, when an entity removing fails, EM throw an exception, but also close the Entity Manager and I cannot use it anymore to delete the remaining colors!

I check `commit` method for `UnitOfWork` class at Doctrine 2 and in fact...

```
try {
    ... //Execute queries

    $conn->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->em->close();
    $conn->rollback();

    throw $e;
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do (maybe reopening Entity Manager)?
Do you believe that there is any better way?
Why Doctrine has this behaviour?

**Also please note that I'm using Doctrine 2 with Symfony 2**

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would define `orphanRemoval` in your relations so you wouldn't need to bother with the removal. Other than that I can think of 3 solutions right now..

First, do you use `CASCADE` in `ON DELETE` when referencing `colors` table?

## 1)

If you do use `CASCADE` I would suggest implementing Doctrine's batch processing as described here: [BULK DELETE](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-deletes) but here your `$batchSize` would be exactly 1.

## 2)

I, somehow, see the above solution as not-so-efficient and you could also achieve this by:

- Going through the entities that reference the `Color` entity and collect `id` of `Color` into the array.
- If that array is not empty, execute: `DELETE FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Color c WHERE c.id IN (:ids)` and set `ids` parameter as usual.

## 3)

There is another solution if you **do not** use `CASCADE`. You could execute **raw sql**:

```
DELETE IGNORE FROM color;
```

Here, referenced colors would not be deleted and would fire an error but due to `IGNORE` it would end up only as warning.

Hope some of this helps....

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, really I should not use cascade delete or `orphanRemoval` because I don't really want to delete all the time the orphan colors. I think I should have mentioned it before, but the task is executed once for database clean purpose, so, I going to figure out the third solution, well, maybe I loose DBMS portability, luckily DBMS requirements are already defined! :)

Comment: Ah yes... in that case **2)** is best suited for you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
// somewhere in ColorRepository.php

$this->createQueryBuilder("o")
    ->leftJoin("o.Relation1", "r1")
    ->leftJoin("o.Relation2", "r2)
    ->where("r1 IS NULL AND r2 IS NULL")
    ->delete() ;
```

This should load your entities (Color) only if they don't have relations with r1 and r2 anymore and delete them.

Comment: this is an interesting solution, although, you would need to have inverse relations to *all* the entities within Color entity... right?

Comment: Thanks, but by model design, I should not use all `Color` inversed relations.

Comment: Yes. I know that doctrine docs say it is not required but I always put them as I find them very, very usefull.

Comment: The reason I always put both sides is like this example: Category hasMany Products. By putting both sides defined, I can read Products from category but also, if I list products, I can read its category like $product->getCategory()->getTitle() or $product->getCategoryTitle() ;